# Why does Windows.Media.BackgroundPlayback.exe crash and can I debug it?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, background-audio

I'm trying to implement BackgroundAudio in my UWP app and I'm following the sample on github. Yet for me before the BackgroundTask gets initialized the output returns `The program '[11864] Windows.Media.BackgroundPlayback.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).`

I can't seem to figure out why though. Is there a way I can debug this?

Edit: I have put the [project online](https://github.com/justijndepover/Soundcloudplus). Seems a lot easier than just copy pasting parts of the code because I don't really understand where it goes wrong

Comment: Showing us the relevant parts of your code is a good start.

Comment: Well I have a breakpoint in the function where I play a music file. Like in the example, it first checks if the task is running. Like this: `if (!IsMyBackgroundTaskRunning || MediaPlayerState.Closed == CurrentPlayer.CurrentState)` But when the breakpoint is hit, VS seems to hang for a while and then it outputs  that the BackgroundPlayback has exited with code 1. I guess I could link the github project here if that would help. But not much of the sample code has been changed. I copy pasted everything from it

Comment: [Error code 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) is apparently `Invalid function`. I don't know if it means that you're calling a function that doesn't exist or something, but you could probably read more about it.

Comment: When I evaluate the BackgroundMedia.Current in my watch I get this `function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out` Could this be related? I don't really get what it means

Comment: Apparently that occurs [when something takes long time to evaluate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2721245/3740093). I'd guess there is something in either of your applications that takes a bit of time executing, and without any code to look at this is a bit hard. You say you have pretty much copy-pasted a Github project. Could you share the link to that project if it's not way to much code? **EDIT:** Oh wait, you already did. I'll try debugging it as soon as I get access to a computer.

Comment: Oh man thanks for the effort you're putting into this. I'm stuck for weeks on this error now and I have no idea what's wrong. I think the reason it says that something took a long time to evaluate is because it crashes, but I'm not sure about that

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but due to that I have Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 I cannot open your project. So I haven't been able to debug it.

Comment: Oh that's okay. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a reference from my task to my main project

Answer (score 0):

If you put your BackgroundTask into WinMD file you will be able to debug it from Visual Studio.

PS: don't forget to add capabilities in manifest

Comment: My Backgroundtask is a part of the solution and I can debug that. But before it even runs it fails because Windows.Media.BackgroundPlayback.exe crashes